# How to create an isolated shell application in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-sdk

I'm trying to create a new visual studio isolated shell application by following the instructions found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb685514%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

I get to step 5: Press F5 to compile and start debugging the solution.  The shell starts to appear, but then this error message appears:

[image: Error]

running MyVSShellStub.exe /resetsettings does not fix the problem.  Does anyone know how to get past this step and have a runnable isolated shell application?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

1) Delete C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0Exp

2) Delete C:\Users\ceelmaa\AppData\Local\Your Company

3) Delete registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0Exp_Config

4) Delete registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0Exp

If that doesn't work, you might want to attack the 11.0 directory & and registry keys. This will affect your visual studio too(you might lose packages).

I think you can reproduce this "bug" if you:

1) compile & run your isolated shell application

2) remove the source code and isolated shell application,

3) do step 1.

I don't understand exactly why this should be happening.

Note: Sometimes it's important to "Clean" the solution and "Rebuild solution". If you run the isolated shell directly, necessary DLLS won't be compiled, etc.